# Ubuntu does not detect new RAM but BIOS does

Tags: hardware, ram

I currently want to increase the RAM of my desktop.  I bought 8Gb, which appears on BIOS but does not appear in Ubuntu. I have tried changing the slots and ubuntu does not find the new one. Also the computer does not start if I only have the new RAM.
Hopefully you can shine some light on this problem.

uname -a output:

```
Linux undred-All-Series 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 19 14:08:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lshw output:

```
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: All Series (All)
    vendor: ASUS
    version: System Version
    serial: System Serial Number
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=desktop family=ASUS MB frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=All uuid=C0F92E3A-DAD7-DD11-973B-305A3A46B293
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: VANGUARD B85
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev 1.xx
       serial: 150850898800494
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 2202
          date: 04/01/2015
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 16MiB
          capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 1
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 0
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 1
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: KHX1600C10D3/8G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 2
             serial: 7A3B9D25
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: KHX1600C10D3/8G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 3
             serial: 713B8B25
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 4a
          slot: CPU Internal L1
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: internal write-back
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 4b
          slot: CPU Internal L2
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 4c
          slot: CPU Internal L3
          size: 6MiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 50
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz
          slot: SOCKET 1150
          size: 2610MHz
          capacity: 3800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 06
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GM206 [GeForce GTX 960]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:32 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GM206 High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:f7120000-f712ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: DWA-171
                   vendor: D-Link Corporation
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@3:1
                   version: 2.00
                   serial: 123456
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=rtl8821cu maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Human interface device
                   product: SteelSeries Rival 300 Gaming Mouse
                   vendor: SteelSeries
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@3:3
                   version: 0.20
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Audio device
                   product: HyperX Virtual Surround Sound
                   vendor: Kingston
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@3:4
                   version: 0.30
                   serial: 00000000
                   capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: USB hub
                   product: ASM107x
                   vendor: ASUS Tek.
                   physical id: a
                   bus info: usb@3:a
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.10
                   configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: ASM107x
                   vendor: ASUS Tek.
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@4:6
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-3.00
                   configuration: driver=hub maxpower=8mA slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:30 memory:f713c000-f713c00f
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eno1
             version: 05
             serial: 30:5a:3a:46:b2:93
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:28 memory:f7100000-f711ffff memory:f7139000-f7139fff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7138000-f71383ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.05
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:31 memory:f7130000-f7133fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: d5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f2000000-f21fffff ioport:f2200000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: d5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge
                vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 04
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7137000-f71373ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.05
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: B85 Express LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:27 ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) memory:f7136000-f71367ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f7135000-f71350ff ioport:f000(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0501
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=serial
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: a
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: b
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: Samsung SSD 850
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 1B6Q
             serial: S21UNXAG632106E
             size: 111GiB (120GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=ab625dcb-9893-4e57-8c3b-6caa2ee58bbf logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                version: FAT32
                serial: 0d8c-5894
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI System Partition
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 184baf0b-24a1-4ff0-98ef-75e40d26951b
                size: 111GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2022-01-04 21:49:12 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2022-02-07 18:01:47 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2022-02-07 18:01:48 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: c
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD10EZEX-00B
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 1A01
             serial: WD-WCC3F6LDJKUE
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=4ac8c61d
           *-volume
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /mnt/disk2
                version: 1.0
                serial: ce07f3a0-e6c2-4408-822a-c11194e8fa58
                size: 931GiB
                capacity: 931GiB
                capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2022-01-24 13:28:43 filesystem=ext4 label=disk 2 lastmountpoint=/mnt/disk2 modified=2022-02-07 18:01:59 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime mounted=2022-02-07 18:01:59 state=mounted
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: d
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: CDDVDW SH-224FB
             vendor: TSSTcorp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: SB00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 1
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: wlx340a33325776
       serial: 34:0a:33:32:57:76
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821cu driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic ip=192.168.1.66 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

dmidecode -t 6 output

```
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
```

lsmem output

```
0x0000000000000000-0x00000000dfffffff  3,5G online       yes  0-27
0x0000000100000000-0x000000021fffffff  4,5G online       yes 32-67

Memory block size:       128M
Total online memory:       8G
Total offline memory:      0B
```

dmidecode --type 17

```
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0042, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0044, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0045, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 7A3B9D25
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: KHX1600C10D3/8G   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x0047, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0043
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Kingston
    Serial Number: 713B8B25
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: KHX1600C10D3/8G   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s
```

dmesg output:

```
[    0.008975] ACPI: Reserving DSDT table memory at [mem 0xdc82b1a0-0xdc83975a]
[    0.008976] ACPI: Reserving FACS table memory at [mem 0xdcd79080-0xdcd790bf]
[    0.008977] ACPI: Reserving APIC table memory at [mem 0xdc839870-0xdc8398e1]
[    0.008978] ACPI: Reserving FPDT table memory at [mem 0xdc8398e8-0xdc83992b]
[    0.008979] ACPI: Reserving LPIT table memory at [mem 0xdc839930-0xdc83998b]
[    0.008980] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdc839990-0xdc839ec8]
[    0.008981] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdc839ed0-0xdc83a9a7]
[    0.008982] ACPI: Reserving MCFG table memory at [mem 0xdc83a9a8-0xdc83a9e3]
[    0.008983] ACPI: Reserving HPET table memory at [mem 0xdc83a9e8-0xdc83aa1f]
[    0.008984] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdc83aa20-0xdc83ad8c]
[    0.008985] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdc83ad90-0xdc83e270]
[    0.008986] ACPI: Reserving BGRT table memory at [mem 0xdc83e378-0xdc83e3af]
[    0.008987] ACPI: Reserving ASF! table memory at [mem 0xdc83e2d0-0xdc83e374]
[    0.009302] Early memory node ranges
[    0.032686] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.032688] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00058000-0x00058fff]
[    0.032690] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.032691] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.032693] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc79a1000-0xc79a1fff]
[    0.032695] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc79b1000-0xc79b1fff]
[    0.032695] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc79b2000-0xc79b2fff]
[    0.032697] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc79d3000-0xc79d3fff]
[    0.032699] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc7b7b000-0xc7b81fff]
[    0.032700] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc7fd6000-0xc845afff]
[    0.032702] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdc61d000-0xdc825fff]
[    0.032703] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdc826000-0xdc83efff]
[    0.032703] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdc83f000-0xdcd7afff]
[    0.032704] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdcd7b000-0xddffefff]
[    0.032706] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xde000000-0xf7ffffff]
[    0.032706] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.032707] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfebfffff]
[    0.032708] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff]
[    0.032708] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec01000-0xfecfffff]
[    0.032709] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed03fff]
[    0.032710] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed04000-0xfed1bfff]
[    0.032710] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed1c000-0xfed1ffff]
[    0.032711] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfedfffff]
[    0.032712] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff]
[    0.032712] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee01000-0xfeffffff]
[    0.032713] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff]
[    0.067353] Memory: 7749592K/8291516K available (16393K kernel code, 3512K rwdata, 10492K rodata, 2904K init, 5724K bss, 541664K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.114171] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
[    0.118619] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
[    0.334625] Freeing initrd memory: 58156K
[    0.476307] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2036K
[    0.476623] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2904K
[    0.493518] Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2036K
[    0.493764] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 1796K
[    0.652026] i2c i2c-0: 2/4 memory slots populated (from DMI)
```

Comment: Are the new and old modules the same speed, width, timing, manufacturer? Boot into `memtest86+` and let it run for a few hours. (Boot holding `Shift`, "Advanced", `memtest86+`)